# Why would the aptitude binary be missing if its package is installed?

Tags: package-management, apt, aptitude, dpkg

Yesterday I upgraded a laptop from Kubuntu 9.04 (Lucid) to 9.10 (Karmic). Then afterwards I tried to install some software

```
$ sudo aptitude install dont-remember-what-it-was
```

and I get

```
sudo: aptitude: command not found
```

Wait, what? How can aptitude be missing? And it's not just that - `apt-get` and `dpkg` also somehow mysteriously vanished from the system. I've manually checked in `/usr/bin` and all the other directories in `$PATH` and verified that the files actually do not exist.

```
$ ls /usr/bin/aptitude
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/aptitude: No such file or directory
```

Thankfully I have two graphical package managers available, Adept Installer and KPackageKit. Both of them report that the `aptitude` package is installed. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it through the GUI, just to be safe, and the uninstall/reinstall seemed to go off without a hitch. But the actual program binaries are still missing.

Is this something normal? If not, has anyone ever heard of it happening? Is it likely that the missing programs will magically reappear if I upgrade to 10.04?

**EDIT:** I have no idea what was going on, but after leaving the computer off overnight and a couple of reboots, the problem seems to have fixed itself. All the right files seem to be there.

Comment: I don't know why you would be but are you chrooted?

Comment: @Oli: This is coming directly off a reboot, so unless my computer has learned to run chroot without my knowledge, I doubt that's the case. (And if it has, I think I may have bigger issues than a missing package manager...)

Comment: I'm surprised that the GUI tools didn't report an error when trying to reinstall dpkg - the GUI tools all use dpkg themselves!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is definitely not normal!

To get dpkg and apt-get back you can do the following:
Download [dpkg_1.15.8.2ubuntu3_i386.deb](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.15.8.2ubuntu3_i386.deb) and [apt_0.7.25.3ubuntu9.1_i386.deb](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.7.25.3ubuntu9.1_i386.deb)

```
ar x dpkg_1.15.8.2ubuntu3_i386.deb
sudo tar -C / -xzf data.tar.gz
ar x apt_0.7.25.3ubuntu9.1_i386.deb
sudo tar -C / -xzf data.tar.gz
```

Note that some packages at internally compressed with lzma instead of gzip, so one would have to use

```
sudo tar --lzma -xf data.tar.lzma
```

Afterwards you should be able to do `apt-get update` and then install aptitude with

```
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude
```

**Warning!**
I really cant recommend that people install packages like this! Be sure to look at the configuration of the specific package, and if any dependency is missing! And if possible reinstall the packages through apt or dpkg afterwards.

Comment: Turned out I didn't need to do this, but it's good to know how I would manually install the packages if needed.

Comment: +1 for showing how to manually install packages.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not normal. I suggest you do a filesystemcheck and also check installed files with md5sum like this:

```
md5sum -c /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.md5sums 2>/dev/null | grep -v OK$
```

And then maybe reinstall the affected packages with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall aptitude
```

Comment: I'll run the FS check but I can't really reinstall aptitude that way since apt-get is missing as well.

Comment: Source Lab's answer should help there. For any package that has md5sum errors you can then use the command above.

Answer (score 0):

When you upgraded, Aptitude was uninstalled for some unknown reason. Most likely, it was a bug in the upgrade. Or, Aptitude was incompatible with the new software.